# Django-CMS slug in if statement in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to write an if statement to change what the link links to, based on the slug URL. I get an error in the if_statement. Shouldn't this work?

```
<div>
    {% if page_attribute "slug" == 'hjem' or page_attribute "slug" == 'home' %}
        <a href="/no/">NO</a> / <a href="/en/">EN</a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="/no/{% page_attribute 'slug' %}">NO</a> / <a href="/en/{% page_attribute 'slug' %}">EN</a>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...

```
{% page_attribute "slug" as page_slug %}

<div>
    {% if page_slug == 'hjem' or page_slug == 'home' %}
        <a href="/no/">NO</a> / <a href="/en/">EN</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="/no/{% page_slug %}">NO</a> / <a href="/en/{% page_slug %}">EN</a>
    {% end if %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use template tags in an "if" statement. You'll have to find some other way to get the slug URL.